# How quickly after a domain expires will it become available for purchase on domain registrar sites?

Tags: dns, registrar

How quickly after a domain expires (that I don't own) will it become available for purchase on domain registrar sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the domain will enter a grace period after it's expired. This lasts 40 days. During this time the domain can be renewed for the same price as regular renewal. After that it enters a redemption period, where it can be renewed for an additional fee. This lasts 30 days. Then it enters the deletion period, which takes 5 days. So the entire process takes 75 days.

Comment: If you're looking to snatch a domain that's going to expire soon. Some sites will allow you to place a "back order" on a domain.